# PHP - Checking if the user is logged on

Tags: php, authentication

I am quite new at PHP, so I hope there are some that can help. 
I have a login page which works fine.
My problem is if you know the url, you can still access the subpages.

This is what it says on my login page

```
<body>
<?php
if(@!empty($_SESSION['acesses'])) {
echo '<script language="JavaScript">{ location.href="subpage.php"; self.focus(); }</script>';
}
?>
<div id="loginWrapper">
<div id="login">
    <form name="loginform" action="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post" autocomplete="on">
        <fieldset id="input">
            <h1>Log Ind</h1>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    echo '<div class="errorBox">';
                    $username = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
                    $password = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

                    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
                        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
                        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

                        if($result['username'] == $username && $result['password'] == $password) {
                            //Sesstion Information
                            $_SESSION['acesses'] = $result['id'];
                            echo '<script language="JavaScript">{ location.href="subpage.php"; self.focus(); }</script>';
                        }else {
                            echo 'Brugernavnet eller Adganskoden stemmer ikke overens.';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            ?>

            <label for="username"> Dit Brugernavn</label>
            <input name="username" id="user" type="text" placeholder="Brugernavn"> 

            <label for="password"> Dit password </label>  
            <input name="password" id="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log ind" />
        </fieldset>   
     </form>
..........
```

This is what it says at the top of my subpage

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['acesses'])) {   
echo '<script language="JavaScript">{ location.href="login.php"; self.focus(); }</script>';
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

Comment: If the user has javascript disabled, they'll never see the subpage. Consider using .htaccess and .htpasswd and checking those values.

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be on line 1 EXACTLY! `<?php session_start();?>` Cannot be anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You could do redirect the user, if they are not logged in, and vice-versa.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['acesses'])){ 
            header("Location: yourpage.php"); // or whatever page you like
            exit();
}
else{  
// your code for when user is logged in 
}
```

**Don't use JavaScript to redirect, especially when dealing with sessions. A user can simply turn off JavaScript in their browser and the redirect won't work anymore.**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your subpage redirects away if the user *isn't* logged in. Second of all, instead of a javascript redirect, use an HTTP one:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['acesses']) || empty($_SESSION['acesses'])) {   
    Header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following logic in the page(s) you wish to protect:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['acesses']) && !empty($_SESSION['acesses'])){
// give access
}

else{
// don't give access
}
```

and do the same for all your pages.

Sidenote: The code you posted for your login page doesn't contain `session_start();` - If it's not in your working code, include it. It must be inside all pages using [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

```
<body>
<?php
session_start();
    if(@!empty($_SESSION['acesses'])) {
    echo '<script language="JavaScript">{ location.href="subpage.php"; self.focus(); }</script>';
    }
?>
```

You should also consider embedding `<noscript>Please enable Javascript</noscript>` into your code and redirect the user if it isn't enabled.

---

***Important sidenote***: I noticed you are storing passwords in plain text. This is ***highly discouraged***.

If your PHP version is 5.5, you can use the [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, or `crypt()` or `bcrypt()`

Here are a few resources you can look into:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt
- http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

---

**About using Javascript:**

If you absolutely want to use JS in your code, you can use the following logic:

```
<?php
    echo "<div id=\"hide\">This line is hidden in PHP and will appear once JS is enabled.</div>";
    // you can include your JS anywhere in here and will execute once the user enables JS.
?>

<body>
<div class="hide_class">This is hidden using a CSS class and will appear once JS is enabled.</div>

<noscript>
Please enable Javascript to view the content of this page, thank you.

    <style>
    #hide {
    display:none;
    }

    .hide_class {
    display:none;
    }
    </style>

</noscript>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use PHP-PDO in order to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Also your code is wrong at subpage. You should check out variable **acesses** like following example.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['acesses']) or empty($_SESSION['acesses'])) {   
echo '<script language="JavaScript">{ location.href="login.php"; self.focus(); }</script>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. 
I will immediately read about PDO and see if I can make an example of it and then change this one.